# Adding Overlayed JLabels

Tags: java, swing, overlay, jlabel

I am creating a swing application ( rip i know ), and want to place 2 JLabels ontop of eachother. Heres the scenario

The game is a birds eye view of an island, with the island separated into grid squares... Now on each of these grid squares, there can be many 1 item and 1 animal. Ive created two JLabels

```
JLabel animal = new JLabel();
JLabel item = new JLabel();
```

and then used `animal.setIcon(...);` to set their image. Now this is working perfectly, but i am wanting to place an image OVER the animal label, so that i can have two visible on the same grid square.

I am writing the following code in a class with extends JPanel, which i later add to a jframe ( This is the gridsquare class )

```
if(inputItem!= null){
            try{
                imgItem = ImageIO.read(inputItem);
                itemLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgItem.getScaledInstance(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
                this.add(itemLabel);
            }catch(Exception e){
                //do something
            }
        }
```

So this works fine. And i do something very similar for the inputAnimal and imgAnimal variables also. Just wondering how i can go about adding them ontop of eachother. I have tried simply adding them sequentially but this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need two labels. You need an [OverlayIcon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088599/how-to-combine-two-icons-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now on each of these grid squares, there can be many 1 item and 1 animal. Ive created two JLabels

You could use the `OverlayLayout`. It allows you to stack components in the Z axis on the same panel.

Or you can just take advantage of the Swing parent / child relationship between components and add a label to another label as long as the parent label uses a layout manager:

```
animal.setLayout(new BorderLayout() );
animal.add( item );
gridSquare.add( animal );
```